# AngularJS Pre filter Setting

Tags: angularjs

i am trying a simple pre filtering:

```
<tr class="{{firm.statusclass}}" dir-paginate="firm in firms|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:search |itemsPerPage:10">
```

this firms got as attribute "actif"  (++/--) how can i set a pre filter with actif : ++ everthing i tried did kill the standard search any idea?

my best try was to add this in my controller:

```
$scope.search= '++';
```

with this  all data with actif:-- was not displayed but i cant change the search and filter values

Comment: your question is unclear you should create a JSFidlle

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple "filter" filters in chain:

```
<tr ng-class="firm.statusclass" dir-paginate="firm in firms | filter:{'actif': '++'} | orderBy:sortKey:reverse | filter:search | itemsperpage:10">
```

Note: You can't use expression with class attribute. Using ng-class instead.

Comment: ok thats fine but now in the next step  i want a selectbox wich alows me to  turn the pre filter off. 

with other words:  i got a list and in the beginning only the ++ should be showing and if the user want so i should be able to switch to  only -- only ++ or booth